# How can I use tethering software together with a wireless trigger for my Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon-d5100, tethering, wireless-triggers

I'm using a Nikon D5100 and I would like to know how to use USB tethering with live view and meanwhile to be able to take photos using a wireless remote trigger.

At the moment, once I open "Capture One",  I cannot control my camera anymore.

Is there any software which allows me to have live on my PC and use a wireless remote trigger to take photo simulaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've tried it with your exact camera, but maybe give this a look?

http://www.sofortbildapp.com

The issue with live view on a computer while taking a picture from the camera is the computer has to be in control of the shutter and sensor in order to do live view. For the camera to re-override that override would be some interesting programming.

If you're already plugged in to the computer, though, why do you need another remote?

Answer (score 0):

When the live view with pc connection is running all other controls are disabled including wireless remote function, this is same behavior for all Nikon cameras

Answer (score 0):

I have a D5000 and I can use it with IR-triggered release tethered with application Darktable under Linux.

I tried it with Live-View enabled and it didn't work. I cannot say whether it is impossible because of the camera features or whether Darktable fails to do this properly.